# Comparing SQL date ranges across multiple nullable date columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a calendar type check I'm trying to do on SQL Server. For each month of the year, I need to check if the employee was hired or not.  There can be an original hire date, a rehire date, a termination date, and the last termination date; other than the original hire date, which will always have a value, all of these date fields can be null.

Given the following data:

```
EmpID   OrigHireDate    TermDate    LastTermDate    RehireDate
42      2017-09-25      NULL        2019-03-26      2019-10-30
```

What I am trying to achieve is the following result for each month for last year (i.e. 2019) and having no luck in coming up with the right statement.  Assume I already have a table containing each month's number along with the start/end date of the month that I can use to compare the date ranges.

```
EmpID   Month   EmployeeDuring
42      1       True
42      2       True
42      3       True
42      4       False
42      5       False
42      6       False
42      7       False
42      8       False
42      9       False
42      10      True
42      11      True
42      12      True
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried...

Comment: The months make no sense unless there is a specific year. The employee posted has worked in every month at one point. They were first employed for more than a year. I would strongly suggest you fix the data model. You should normalize this into a table that makes more sense. EmpID, ActivityDate, ActivityID. Then a second table with ActivityID and a text explanation. That aside I don't understand your business rules here at all.

Comment: I basically need to account for the previous year (so 2019) what their status was every month including if they were an employee for the first part not employed the second part and then rehired at the end through the end of the year.

Comment: I agree with Sean - the data model seems broken here. What if the same employee gets rehired the 3rd time, for example? also, `TermDate` and `LastTermDate` doesn't seem very descriptive - suppose you hire someoneand then fire them - should that date be populated in the TermDate or LastTermDate column? Why?

Comment: Unfortunately broken or not, it's what I have to work with and what I'm expected to account accurately for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following works. May need some minor adjustments to handle all possible combinations of EmpID, OrigHireDate, TermDate, LastTermDate, RehireDate

I apologize for posting mostly code. Will add more explanation and or comments tomorrow.

```
DECLARE @EmpID int, @OrigHireDate date,    @TermDate date,    @LastTermDate date,    @RehireDate date
DECLARE @year int

SET @year = 2019

SET @EmpID = 42
SET @OrigHireDate = '2017-09-25'
SET @TermDate = NULL
SET @LastTermDate = '2019-03-26'
SET @RehireDate = '2019-10-30'

SET @OrigHireDate = DATEADD(day,-DAY(@OrigHireDate)+1, @OrigHireDate)
SET @LastTermDate = DATEADD(day,-DAY(ISNULL(@LastTermDate,GETDATE()))+1, @LastTermDate)
SET @RehireDate = DATEADD(day,-DAY(@RehireDate)+1, @RehireDate)
SET @TermDate = DATEADD(day,-DAY(ISNULL(@TermDate,GETDATE()))+1, @TermDate)

;WITH CTE_DATES_ORIGINAL([Date],[Level])
AS
(
    SELECT @OrigHireDate AS [DATE],
    1 AS [Level]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(MONTH,1, [DATE] )  , [Level] + 1  
    FROM CTE_DATES_ORIGINAL
    WHERE [DATE] < ISNULL(@LastTermDate,GETDATE())
),
CTE_DATES_REHIRE([Date],[Level])
AS
(
    SELECT @RehireDate AS [DATE],
    1 AS [Level]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(MONTH,1, [DATE] )  , [Level] + 1  
    FROM CTE_DATES_REHIRE
    WHERE [DATE] < ISNULL(@TermDate,GETDATE())
),
CTE_DATES_YEAR(m) AS
(
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT m+1 
    FROM CTE_DATES_YEAR
    WHERE m < 12
)

SELECT @EmpID AS EmpID, m AS [Month], ISNULL(EmployeeDuring.EmployeeDuring,0) AS EmployeeDuring
FROM CTE_DATES_YEAR y
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(
SELECT 
[Date], 1 AS EmployeeDuring
FROM 
    CTE_DATES_ORIGINAL 
UNION 
SELECT 
[Date] , 1 AS EmployeeDuring
FROM 
    CTE_DATES_REHIRE 
) employeeDuring
ON DATEADD(month,m-1, CAST(CAST(@year AS CHAR(4)) + '-1-1' AS DATE)) = employeeDuring.[Date]
ORDER BY m
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 5000)
```

Comment: This helped a bit. Not entirely but have me enough to think about to proceed a bit further. So while this didn't 100% answer, I'm marking it as the answer since it was helpful.